Android Emulator for AVD has terminated on Fedora
I am running Fedora and Android AVD Emulator simply won't start. It worked on Ubuntu 22.04, Fedora gives a lot of issues.
The emulator does seem to start (grey screen), then hangs and then says The emtulator process for AVD has terminated.
CompileCommand: exclude com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot.trieDescend bool exclude = true
2024-08-13 10:48:55,165 [ 726] WARN - #c.i.s.ComponentManagerImpl - com.android.tools.idea.flags.StudioFlags requests com.android.tools.idea.flags.StudioFlagSettings instance. Class initialization must not depend on services. Consider using instance of the service on-demand instead.
2024-08-13 10:48:55,386 [ 947] WARN - #c.i.n.i.NotificationGroupManagerImpl - Notification group Logcat is already registered (group=com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup@6a3f5dd3). Plugin descriptor: PluginDescriptor(name=Android, id=org.jetbrains.android, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=~/Documents/software/android-studio/plugins/android, version=241.18034.62.2411.12169540, package=null, isBundled=true)
2024-08-13 10:48:59,613 [ 5174] WARN - #com.android.ddmlib - * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
2024-08-13 10:49:00,617 [ 6178] WARN - #com.android.ddmlib - * daemon started successfully
2024-08-13 10:49:01,375 [ 6936] WARN - #c.i.u.j.JBCefApp - JCefAppConfig.class is not from a JBR module, url: jar:file:/home/asus/Documents/software/android-studio/lib/lib.jar!/com/jetbrains/cef/JCefAppConfig.class (Use JBR bundled with the IDE)
2024-08-13 10:49:01,953 [ 7514] WARN - Emulator: Pixel 7 Pro API 33 - Failed to process .ini file /home/asus/.android/avd/…/avd/Pixel_7_Pro_API_33.avd/quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
2024-08-13 10:49:02,300 [ 7861] WARN - Emulator: Pixel 7 Pro API 33 - The emulator now requires a signed jwt token for gRPC access! Use the -grpc flag if you really want an open unprotected grpc port
2024-08-13 10:49:02,304 [ 7865] WARN - Emulator: Pixel 7 Pro API 33 - *** Basic token auth should only be used by android-studio ***
2024-08-13 10:49:02,594 [ 8155] WARN - Emulator: Pixel 7 Pro API 33 - Device ‘cache’ does not have the requested snapshot ‘default_boot’
2024-08-13 10:49:02,594 [ 8155] WARN - Emulator: Pixel 7 Pro API 33 - Failed to load snapshot ‘default_boot’


Tried changing gpu mode from hardware to software (with hardware nothing came, with software at least emulator with grey screen came).
increased size memory

